# how to change vuejs component data on one device when data in db updated by other device without refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, vue.js

i want to know, how to change vuejs component data on my device if the data had been changed my other user from other device without refreshing page.

for example an admin watching user data on his screen and at the same time user update his data from his own device and the db data updated. Then the admin screen  data should be updated automatically without refreshing the page or without clicking some sort of refresh page button. dom data should be updated.

can anyone give me some idea.

Comment: If you wish to do updates almost immediately then look at websockets or some lib like https://socket.io

Comment: Another way to do this without adding a new framework is have your pages continually refetch page data. It's not the same, and if you want something that works quickly without having to add a whole new framework, that's doable pretty quickly

Comment: what do you mean by that? @LannyBose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As @Anatoly said, If we wish to do updates almost immediately then look at
   WebSockets or some lib like socket.io
2. **Short polling**: means hit API after a specific time interval.
3. Use some `language/frame` that can control concurrency on the server,
   means language which can program threads and processes on the server. then this one will generate a channel using continuous `process & thread`  and whoever is connected to the channel will get real-time interaction like sockets. In other words, by using this approach you can create your own socket without any third-party package (useful for larger applications i.e Banking, Blockchain, Rescue Service etc).

Answer (score 0):

use websocket, web-server actively send data to web-page